# MySQL KILL - Process immediately respawns

Tags: mysql, node.js, coffeescript, node-orm2

I wrote a Cron job to kill processes that have been sleeping for too long. However, when I kill a process, it immediately respawns. What's restarting these processes? Is it a MySQL setting?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
db.driver.execQuery 'select * from information_schema.processlist where time > 2000', (err, threads) ->
  if err? then return
  if !threads? then return
  for thread in threads
    do (thread) ->
      db.driver.execQuery 'kill ' + thread.ID, (err, response) ->
       console.log 'Killed thread that was ' + thread.TIME + ' seconds old'
```

Comment: can be  innumerous things, like a monitor process.. try to identify by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql does not retry queries, it must be the application that was running it -- the app detects the killed query as a server error, and must be immediately retrying it